# symfony date_default_timezone_set Notice: Object of class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference could not be converted to int

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to set the timezone in AppKernel.php

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
    parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
}
```

but it does not work i am getting this error:

*Notice: Object of class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference could not be converted to int*

i have cleared cache many times, if i remove the above code then i get following error:

*date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.*

Note: the application work perfectly on my machine but i need to deploy the code on Test server I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default time zone on your php.ini

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
```

Another way

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
    {
        // Other methods and variables


        // Append this init function below

        public function init()
        {
            date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Berlin' );
            parent::init();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Same error 

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Object of class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference could not be converted to int" at /var/www/httpdocs/test/cms/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php line 65

Comment: Please, what is the symfony version? it is 2.4 ?

Comment: symfony version 2.7.3

Comment: Try to set it in your php.ini. launch :

php -i |grep php.ini

to see where is your actual cli's php.ini
then set the time zone:
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"

Comment: But the problem is the hosting provider doesn't give access to php.ini file

Comment: I think you should debug on vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php before line 65 in _isFresh(TemplateReferenceInterface $template, $time)_ function

Comment: have you found the answer?